# Facebook login shows error message in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on Facebook integration on my Android app. It's working fine on some device, but on some device it's not working and give me error message:

[image]

Below is the code :

```
 private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };



    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (   exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) 
        {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindow.this)
                    .setTitle("cancel")
                    .setMessage("your permission has expired.")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                    .show();

        } 

    }




private void onClickFacebookRequest() 
 {
        if (session.isOpened()) 
        {
            sendRequests();

        } else {
            StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindow.this)
                                .setTitle(R.string.login_failed_dialog_title)
                                .setMessage(exception.getMessage())
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null)
                                .show();
                     session = createSession();
                    }
                }
            };
            pendingRequest = true;


            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
        }
    }
 private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";

 private void sendRequests() 
 {

     List<String> permissions = quytechApps.getSession().getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingRequest = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        showValidationDialog("Please Wait.posting Data on Facebook");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.splash_screen_final4);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        Bundle postParams=new Bundle();
        postParams.putByteArray("photo",byteArray);
        postParams.putString("message", "Hi Friends I am using Twinqli Chat App.");

        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            if(response.getError() == null)
            {
                Log.d("GraphApiSample.java Sucesses","sucess");
                dismissValidatingDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                dismissValidatingDialog();
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                //quytechApps.getSession().
                //quytechApps.setSession(null);
//                  Log.d("GraphApiSample.java",""+response.getError().getErrorMessage());
            }

            }

        });
        request.executeAsync();
 }

 private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

 static final String applicationId = "390611174384274";
 boolean pendingRequest;
 static final String PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.samples.graphapi:PendingRequest";

 private Session createSession() 
 {
        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) 
        {
            activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
        }
        return activeSession;
    }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (qsession.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data) &&
                pendingRequest &&
                session.getState().isOpened()) {
            sendRequests();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        pendingRequest = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem normally occurs when the **facebook app** in your phone is not **updated** so please update it and then check.
It worked for me hope it will work for you also.

**EDIT:**
To check the hash key put this in your **onCreate** Method

```
 PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.yourpackagename", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Exactly the problem as Abhishek Agarwal said.

Comment: hey Abhishek thanks for answer.. Now i update my facebook app. Now it shows me Login Failed error dialog with message : remote_app_id does not match stored id. but my remote_app_id and stored id in app both are same and also its works fine in other phone.

Comment: No its not asking about hask key or like that . I have already add hash key in facebook app when create facebook app.

Comment: Is the facebook app in sand box mode?If yes, change it to visible to all.

Comment: i have done it already. SandBox Mode is off and app is to visisble to all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34123/discussion-between-abhishek-agarwal-and-nitin-tyagi)